# Dynamically create an HTML list from Javascript object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a JavaScript project, and I have an object that contains an array of items. I need to parse these items and display them in an HTML list. I'm wondering what the best approach is for this task.

Here's a simplified example of the JavaScript object structure:

Javascript

```
const myObject = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Example Object',
  items: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', /* ... */]
};
```

I want to extract the items array and dynamically create an HTML list, something like:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

What would be the best way to achieve this in JavaScript?

I appreciate any guidance you can provide. Thank you!